# Buttons that take you to the FIRST and LAST slide in SPLIDEJS

Tags: javascript, html, splidejs

I am using [**SPLIDEJS**](https://splidejs.com)
[**MY EXAMPLE PAGE**](https://pollentung.com/splidetest/)

I need assistance making arrows that take you to the FIRST and LAST page of the slider. This is an important feature due to it being for a webcomic. I looked into the i18n and played around with it enough that I hit a wall.

Trying to think of how to Frankenstein an understanding with this [GITHUB ISSUE ANSWER](https://github.com/Splidejs/splide/issues/275#issuecomment-797268426) and the [EVENTS](https://splidejs.com/guides/events/), [API](https://splidejs.com/guides/apis/) and [CONTROLLER?](https://splidejs.com/components/controller/).

```
var splide = new Splide( '#splide' ).mount();

// Go to first slide.
splide.go( 0 );
```

I have made a compromise by linking the first and last slide but that is not automatic in any way. Being a one-man-team for this comic means I need as much automated as possible so I can focus on actually making the stuff. I truly appreciate this, thank you!